# time in x-axis not showing correctly when superimposing scatter plots in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I was trying to plot a trend line with superimposed outlier point on it. The outliers are either higher than the upper band or lower than the lower band. The problem is that when I try to plot some of the superimposed outlier, the index will go wrong and give me a broken image.

I have been trying to fix this for hours and finally noticed if I switch the plotting order this would work. I could not understand what went wrong and would like some insights! Thanks!

Code that works:

```py
ax = sp[sp.counts > sp.upper].counts.plot(marker='D',linestyle='none',label='increase')
sp.plot(ax=ax)
sp[sp.counts < sp.lower].counts.plot(marker='D',linestyle='none',label='decrease')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

Correct Image:

[image: Correct Image]

Code that does not:

```py
ax = sp.plot()
sp[sp.counts > sp.upper].counts.plot(marker='D',ax=ax,linestyle='none',label='upper')
sp[sp.counts <= sp.lower].counts.plot(marker='D',linestyle='none',label='lower')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

Not working Image:

[image: Not working Image]

And if I remove the `sp[sp.counts <= sp.lower]` one, it will work again. (And the `sp[sp.counts > sp.upper]` one is doing fine!)

Here are other ways I've tried to fix the code above and did not work:

1. use matplotlib instead of pandas plotting
2. use `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` to define the ax
3. switch the order of two outlier plots
4. use only one outlier set `sp[(sp.counts < sp.lower) | (sp.counts > sp.upper)]`, this actually works but will only have one color.

Here's the DataFrame Structure:

**sp.counts[sp.counts > sp.upper]**

> time
>
> 2015-11-01    6369
>
> 2015-11-08    6502
>
> 2015-11-22    6505
>
> 2015-12-06    6589
>
> 2015-12-13    6674
>
> 2016-09-25    6791
>
> 2016-11-20    7051
>
> Name: counts, dtype: int64

**sp[sp.counts < sp.lower]**

> time
>
> 2015-05-31    5841
>
> 2015-12-27    5526
>
> 2016-11-27    6117
>
> Name: counts, dtype: int64

**sp.tail(5)**

> ```py
>          counts      ave     upper     lower
> ```
>
> time
>
> 2017-08-27     6956  6834.25  7083.758  6584.742
>
> 2017-09-03     6794  6828.30  7075.566  6581.034
>
> 2017-09-10     6694  6815.85  7063.873  6567.827
>
> 2017-09-17     6784  6810.35  7055.943  6564.757
>
> 2017-09-24     6889  6805.70  7040.911  6570.489

Comment: Thanks for helping with the image! @heltonbiker I do not have the reputation to insert it yet

Comment: Is this question answered? Should the 'code that works' be the answer to the question?

Comment: @ScottSkiles Not really, my question is why switching the order of outlier graph and main counts graph would work, but not with the two outlier graphs. I really don't want to just move on with the code that works, but meet the same problem next time...